# CFWheels form without objectName for design purposes

Tags: forms, coldfusion, textfield, form-helpers, cfwheels

Is it possible to create a form using form helpers without having an object to link the form to? I want to just design a form and have it render, but I don't have an object to point to yet. Or, is there a simple way to create a dummy object? For instance,

```
<p>#textField(objectName="dummy", property="name", label="Name")#</p>
```

`objectName` seems to be a required parameter.  http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-3/function/textfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CfWheels, there are four types of form helper functions:

1. form object functions
2. form tag functions
3. Form Association functions
4. General form functions

The one you are using is form object function which requires object and there are other functions (form tag functions) like bellow that don't require object to bind to:

1. textFieldTag()
2. fileFieldTag()
3. checkBoxTag() 
   etc....
   Check out all [form tag functions][1]

   [1]: http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-0/function/category/view-helper category.
   I hope this helps.